# How can I drag and drop text from one Emacs window into another?

Tags: emacs, drag-and-drop

Is it possible to select text in one Emacs window and then drag-drop it into another window of the same Emacs session?

If so, how can it be done?

Comment: In what operating system? If Linux, which Desktop Environment or Window Manager?

Comment: I actually use both Windows 7 (Windows) and Ubuntu 13.10 (Linux). Is there a cross-platform solution?

Comment: Don't think so, but I'm not sure. Personally, I just copy/paste.

Comment: There are left / right mouse-up and mouse-down keys, so you could trigger paste with . . . mouse-up . . . and you could use `(mouse-set-point event)` before the paste -- take a look at `mouse.el` and `mouse-copy.el` and `mouse-drag.el`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define "drag-drop it into another".  Mouse-dragging in Emacs selects text -- see `(emacs) Mouse Commands`.  Do you mean pasting selected text into a different Emacs window in the same Emacs session?   In a different session?

If you just want to copy text from one Emacs window to another using the mouse, then select it and then use `mouse-2` to paste it.  To copy+paste to a different Emacs session, you might need to set some variables (depends on your platform/setup), to have mouse selection also copy the selction to the interprogram clipboard etc.  See `(emacs) Primary Selection`.

On MS Windows, I use these settings, FWIW:

- `mouse-2` is bound to `mouse-yank-at-click`
- `select-active-regions` is `t`
- `x-select-enable-clipboard` is `t`
- `mouse-drag-copy-region` is `t`

Comment: I had discovered the same solution and was going to mention `mouse-2` in an answer. Yes, same Emacs session. Question updated.